# How are implicits useful inside a Play template

Tags: playframework-2.0

[Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplates) mentions implicit reusable blocks. Can you expand from the one-liner mentioned there and copied below, to show how such blocks would be used in a Play html template?

`@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ MyFieldConstructor() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this idea is expanded in farther part of the [Custom Field Constructors documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors) where you can find an example related to form construction.

When you create a form in Play framework you can make use of form helpers to simplify creation of reusable inputs. Play contains several built-in helpers and each of them takes a field constructor as an implicit parameter.

Imagine a following form created in a view.

```
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ helper.FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }

@helper.form(action = routes.Application.handlePost()) {
  @helper.inputText(userForm("name"))
  @helper.inputText(userForm("surname"))
  @helper.inputText(userForm("login"))
  @helper.inputText(userForm("password"))
}
```

The *inputText* [apply](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/views/html/helper/inputText$.html) method takes *FieldConstructor* as an implicit parameter. As you can see a template implicit is used to provide a value for the apply method without passing it explicitly to each of *inputText* call. Thanks to implicit parameter the form definition in the view looks more concise and clearer.